# How to implement multiples parameters with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a script that returns the values ​​of my worksheet in JSON format, but I wanted to type two parameters to return the items that contain the 2 values

example: url.com/.../exec?nome=thiago&id=2

How would I implement req.parameters in this code?

```
function doGet(req) {
    var nome = req.parameter.nome;
    var id = req.parameter.id;
    var uid = req.parameter.uid;
    var msg = req.parameter.msg;
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('chat_animeit');
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    var output = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        var row = {};
        row['ID'] = values[i][0];
        row['UID'] = values[i][1];
        row['Nome'] = values[i][2];
        row['Perfil'] = values[i][3];
        row['Mensagem'] = values[i][4];
        output.push(row);
    }

    if(nome != null) {
        var outputToReturn = output.filter(obj => obj.Nome.toLowerCase().toString().includes(nome.toLowerCase()));
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"results": outputToReturn})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
    else if(id != null) {
        var outputToReturn = output.filter(obj => obj.ID.toLowerCase().toString().includes(id.toString()));
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"results": outputToReturn})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
    else if(uid != null) {
        var outputToReturn = output.filter(obj => obj.UID.toLowerCase().toString().includes(uid.toLowerCase()));
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"results": outputToReturn})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
    else if(msg != null) {
        var outputToReturn = output.filter(obj => obj.Mensagem.toLowerCase().toString().includes(msg.toLowerCase()));
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"results": outputToReturn})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
    else {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"results": output})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm creating an API to fetch data from my spreadsheet.

I need that when writing two parameters in the url, the API brings me the filter for both.

Example:

```
ID  UID         Nome    Perfil      Mensagem

1   ASF15ASF5   THIAGO  https:...   Testes de Mensagem para a api 1
1   ASF15ASF    CARLOS  https:...   Teste de Mensagem para a api
3   ASF15ASF    GOOGLE  https:...   Teste de Mensagem para a api
1   ASF15ASF    THIAGO  https:...   Teste de Mensagem para a api 2
2   ASF15ASF5   THIAGO  https:...   Testes de Mensagem para a api 3
2   ASF15ASF5   THIAGO  https:...   Coisas
3   ASF15ASF    GOOGLE  https:...   coisas
```

When using the parameters

```
?id=2&msg=coisas
```

the API returns me only the line that has the 2 values.

In this case it would return:

```
ID  UID         Nome    Perfil      Mensagem

2   ASF15ASF5   THIAGO  https:...   Coisas
```

but currently I can only use one parameter at a time

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal from `I'm creating a script that returns the values ​​of my worksheet in JSON format, but I wanted to type two parameters to return the items that contain the 2 values example: url.com/.../exec?nome=thiago&id=1305 How would I implement req.parameters in this code?`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, it seems that your columns are `ID, Name, Message`. But, in your showing script, it seems that the columns are `ID, UID, Nome, Perfil, Mensagem`. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, it seems that your columns are `ID, Name, Message`. But, in your showing script, it seems that the columns are `ID, UID, Nome, Perfil, Mensagem`. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: I just translated and simplified the terms, so you could understand better.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated `Example:`, it seems that it is different from your sheet of "chat_animeit". So, unfortunately, I'm confusing your question. I apologize for this. Your updated `Example:` is the same with "chat_animeit" or it is different from "chat_animeit"?

Comment: I corrected and added more examples

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your "Example:". About `?id=2&msg=coisas` of `When using the parameters`, in your situation, you will always use `id` and `msg`, and you will not use other parameters? And they are `ID` and `Mensagem`, respectively? I cannot understand the columns corresponding to your query parameters. I apologize for this.

Comment: I just need to make it so that when using 2 or more parameters in the url it returns me the lines that contain the values ​​that are in the parameter

take a look at the "pagination" section of this api: https://animechan.vercel.app/docs they use "title=naruto" to call the anime naruto and "page=2" to call the second page of the anime "naruto "

Comment: Basically a search system that will simultaneously search the values ​​defined in ALL parameters (or just one of them).

Comment: if I use "name=" and "msg=" the API will return items that contain the values ​​of "name=" and "msg=" simultaneously.
If you search for "id=", "name=" and "msg=" the API will also return items containing the values ​​of "id=", "name=" and "msg=" simultaneously

Comment: id returns the ID;
uid return UID;
nome returns the Nome;
msg returns Mensagem;

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I think, is that you use `if...else if...` so it can only take one filter at a time.

Use several `if` so your resulting data get filtered and filtered and filtered and so on.

A bit of pseudo code, re-using your `output` variable

```
if(condition1) { // if the filter has a value in the URL
  output = output.filter(entry => entry.someField == someValue)
}

if(condition2) { // it will be added to condition1 if there were, otherwise not
  output = output.filter(entry => entry.someOtherField == someOtherValue)
}

/*
once you have been through all the possible conditions,
return the resulting - filtered - data
*/
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"results": output})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

In that way, it's like doing an AND with all the conditions.